# difference それで、だから、ですから

Tags: words

例えば、将来の夢は自分の店を持ちたいです。それで or ですから or だから、今大学生で料理の作り方を勉強しています。

質問：

1. 'ですから'は'だから'より丁寧ですが、でも、この'それで'とは違いがありますか？
2. この文をちょっと変えたら、「将来の夢は………持ちたいんですが、ですから or だから or それで、」この状況は正しいですか？ 'だから'はよく文の始めの位置にありますから。違うなら、どの言葉を使ったらいいですか。

Comment: 「不同が存在ですか」がわかりません。どういう意味ですか。

Comment: is there difference?

Comment: 「どう違いますか」と言いたがっているはずですね。

Comment: 不同が存在しますか。こう言った方がいいと思います。

Comment: あ、そゆことね・・・-----

Comment: すみませんが、初心者ですから、間違いが簡単にあります。

Comment: 「違いはありますか？」is how you ask if there's a difference. Please note that "不同が存在ですか" makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, それで would roughly translate to "and so", which I think is perfectly fine.

だから does not sound good, so it's better to avoid it.

If you want to use a polite form of "therefore", you can say なので if it's at the beginning of the sentence, or ので if it's to connect to phrases without a sentence break.

〇〇なりたい**ので**今は……